# Stripe Subscription plan switching issue

Tags: php

I've created one monthly subscription in stripe, after 15 days I switched to  Yearly plan, but I want that the new plan charge will get applied after the first plan is completed then after start new yearly plan and invoice & charges should be applied after my current plan expires, how it possible?

```
$numDays = abs("//old plan end Date" - time())/60/60/24;
\Stripe\Subscription::update($subscriptionId, [
        'cancel_at_period_end' => false,
        'items'                => [
            [
                'id'   => // set Old planid,
                'plan' => // new plan id,
            ],
        ],
        'billing' => 'send_invoice',
        'days_until_due' => numDays,
        'prorate' => false
    ]);
```